# NestJS testing controller can't resolve connection dependency

Tags: testing, jestjs, controller, nestjs

I wrote a test for a NestJS Controller that was working somehow, but now I get this error:

```
describe('ModalityController', () => {
  let controller: ModalityController;
  let modalitiesFactory: Modality[];

  const mockService = {
    getAll: jest.fn(),
    createOne: jest.fn(),
    updateOne: jest.fn(),
  };

  beforeAll(async (done) => {
    await useSeeding();
    modalitiesFactory = await factory(Modality)().makeMany(10);
    done();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [ModalityController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'Connection',
          useValue: {},
        },
        {
          provide: ModalityService,
          useValue: mockService,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<ModalityController>(ModalityController);
  });


  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

I get this error:

```
  ModalityController
    × should be defined (21 ms)

  ● ModalityController › should be defined

    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the de8e6b44-c5c0-4633-b3b4-638e9df1b2a3 (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If Connection is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If Connection is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing Connection */ ]
      })

      at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:193:19)
      at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:149:33)
      at resolveParam (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:103:38)
          at async Promise.all (index 0)
      at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:118:27)
      at Injector.loadInstance (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:47:9)
      at Injector.loadInjectable (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:65:9)
          at async Promise.all (index 2)
      at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfInjectables (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:62:9)
      at ../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:30:13

  ● ModalityController › should be defined

    expect(received).toBeDefined()

    Received: undefined

      46 |
      47 |   it('should be defined', () => {
    > 48 |     expect(controller).toBeDefined();
         |                        ^
      49 |   });
      50 |
      51 |   /*

      at Object.<anonymous> (modality/modality.controller.spec.ts:48:24)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.604 s
```

I also tried to load the Modality Service and then provide a mock of the Modality Repository:

```
 providers: [
        ModalityService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Modality),
          useValue: mockRepository,
        },
      ],
```

But no luck. I don't know how to provide a mocking connection object. What part of the controller is requiring the connection if this is the service job?

Help me guys. What can you see?

EDIT: Adding the controller code:

```
@ApiTags('Modalidad')
@Controller('modality')
export class ModalityController {
  constructor(private modalityService: ModalityService) {}

  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Lista de todas las modalidades, paginados',
  })
  @OpenApiPaginationResponse(UpdateModalityDto)
  @SkipJwtAuth()
  @Get()
  index(@Query() { items_per_page, page }: PaginationDto) {
    return this.modalityService.getAll({
      items_per_page: items_per_page || 10,
      page: page || 0,
      sortOrder: 'ASC',
    });
  }

  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'obtiene una modalidad a partir de una id',
  })
  @ApiParam({
    name: 'id',
    type: Number,
  })
  @SkipJwtAuth()
  @OpenApiTransformResponse(UpdateModalityDto)
  @UseInterceptors(TransformInterceptor)
  @Get(':id')
  getOne(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe, EntityPipe()) modality: Modality) {
    return modality;
  }

  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'Crear una nueva modalidad',
  })
  @SkipJwtAuth()
  @OpenApiTransformResponse(UpdateModalityDto, 201)
  @UseInterceptors(TransformInterceptor)
  @Post()
  async store(@Body() modality: CreateModalityDto) {
    return await this.modalityService.createOne(modality);
  }

  @ApiOperation({
    summary: 'actualizar una modalidad que ya existe',
  })
  @ApiParam({
    name: 'id',
    type: Number,
  })
  @SkipJwtAuth()
  @OpenApiTransformResponse(UpdateModalityDto)
  @UseInterceptors(TransformInterceptor)
  @InjectItemToBody({ property: 'id' })
  @Put(':id')
  async update(
    @Param('id', ParseIntPipe, EntityPipe()) modality: Modality,
    @Body() updatedModality: UpdateModalityDto,
  ) {
    return await this.modalityService.updateOne(modality, updatedModality);
  }
}
```

SOLVED

The problem was that was not detecting the `'Connection'` as a valid value. i've change it to the `Connection` object from the typeorm package

Comment: Can you add the `ModalityController`? Just to see what all it has with it? Strange that the `provide: 'Connection'` isn't working

Comment: Sure, let me update the question

Comment: It's probably `EntityPipe()`, which looks to be fetching and retrieving the model right from the DB.  Try moving `getOne`'s logic to your service and see if that fixes it.